# How to read data from rom_type in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

How can I read data from rom_type?

```
entity my_rom is
 port(
  addr: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  data: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
 );
end my_rom;
architecture a of my_rom is

 type rom_type is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
 constant R1_ROM: rom_type :=
 (
  -- data
 );
begin
 data <= R1_rom(conv_integer(addr));
end a;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `conv_integer`, which is not part of raw VHDL... it's in a library.  However, you don't want to use it -  [it's from a non-standard library](http://parallelpoints.com/node/3).

Instead `use ieee.numeric_std.all;` is what you need before your entity.  Then use `to_integer(unsigned(addr))` to index the ROM. Better still, pass the address in as an `unsigned` vector, or even directly as an `integer`.

Try to get out of the habit of using `std_logic_vector` (which is just a bag of bits) to represent numbers, and use the well-defined numerical types.

Or use Verilog, which doesn't care :)

Myself, I prefer VHDL's strong-typing to keep me from daft foot-shooting...