# Read VHDL data from another architecture

Tags: vhdl

I need to read data from a defined VHDL (.vhd) file. The file is like this:

```
entity ROM is
    port ( address : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           data : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) );
end entity ROM;

architecture behavioral of ROM is
    type ROM is array ( 0 to 2**4 - 1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    constant my_ROM : ROM := (
        0  => "00000000",
        1  => "00000001");

begin

    data <= my_ROM(to_integer(unsigned(address)));

end architecture behavioral;
```

I know similar question has been posted, *[How to read data from rom_type in VHDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826049)*, but I think I still need help on it. Let's say I have another .vhd file, how should I get the data stored inside this ROM entity?

Comment: Besides the missing context clause (e.g. `library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.numeric_std.all;`) your code sample doesn't analyze. The aggregate used to supply a default value doesn't have a matching element for each element in the ROM array type. (You should have added an others choice).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an address and data signal to connect to the ROM entity in this architecture. For example;

```
signal rom_address : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal rom_data    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Then you can add the following instantiation to your architecture.

```
somelabel : entity work.ROM 
  port map (
     address => rom_address,
     data    => rom_data
  );
```

You need to drive the `rom_address` signal to get the data from the corresponding addresses in your ROM.

What you could also do is declare this entity as a component in a package or in the architecture from which are going to instantiate it.
The component declaration looks like this;

```
component ROM is
  port (
    address : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    data    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end component;
```

This allows you to instantiate this entity as a component in your architecture.

```
somelabel : ROM 
  port map (
     address => rom_address,
     data    => rom_data
  );
```

Comment: Direct instantiation of entity is also possible with `somelabel : entity work.ROM` to replace `somelabel : ROM`, whereby tedious declaration of a component in package or architecture can be skipped.